# How to use ORDER BY in a query which is containing JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

I have a query which selects all comments for each post. Here is my query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.content, u.name, u.reputation, SUM(v.value) AS total_vote_comments
FROM comments c
INNER JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN votes_comments v ON c.id = v.comment_id
WHERE c.post_id = :id;
```

Now I want to add `ORDER BY c.id` to that query. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `order by` is irrelevant because this query returns one row:

```
SELECT c.id, c.content, u.name, u.reputation, SUM(v.value) AS total_vote_comments
FROM comments c INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON c.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN
     votes_comments v
     ON c.id = v.comment_id
WHERE c.post_id = :id;
```

This is an aggregation query (because of the `SUM()`) without a `GROUP BY`.  Such a query *always* returns one row, even when no rows match the join.

You probably want a `GROUP BY`.  My best guess is:

```
SELECT c.id, c.content, u.name, u.reputation, SUM(v.value) AS total_vote_comments
FROM comments c INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON c.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN
     votes_comments v
     ON c.id = v.comment_id
WHERE c.post_id = :id
GROUP BY c.id, c.content, u.name, u.reputation
ORDER BY c.id;
```

Comment: Look at me ... You are really good in MySQL *(or maybe in all databases)* and thanks for your answer.

Comment: Just one question. if I have this in `SELECT` clause `CONCAT(SUBSTR(col, 1, 9), IF(LENGTH(subject_f) > 9,' ...','')) newcol`, then I have to add `newcol` in `GROUP BY` too?

Comment: @stack . . . I think you should.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the `ORDER BY` clause at the end:

```
SELECT c.id, c.content, u.name, u.reputation, SUM(v.value) AS total_vote_comments
FROM comments c
INNER JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN votes_comments v ON c.id = v.comment_id
WHERE c.post_id = :id
ORDER BY c.id;
```

Comment: Ok thanks, Just one thing, Should I use `GROUP BY` in that query? *(because there is `SUM()` in `SELECT` statement)*

Comment: In MySQL you don't have to specify the `GROUP BY` clause when using an aggregate function, although it is good practice to do so. So yes, you should add a `GROUP BY` clause on `c.id, c.content, u.name, u.reputation`

Comment: I see. Thanks again. +1

Comment: I agree with Jaco.  You can get away with not having a GROUP BY in MySQL, but you couldn't on many databases - you'd get a syntax error.  There isn't a lot of logical use for not using group by in a query of this nature.

Answer (score 0):

By using this query you get only one row which id you put in where clause.
If you want to get one post ordered then you write order by in last.
If you want to get last's comment first so use desc with order by.

**SELECT c.id, c.content, u.name, u.reputation, SUM(v.value) AS total_vote_commentFROM comments c INNER JOIN users u ON c.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN votes_comments v ON c.id = v.comment_id WHERE c.post_id = :id order by id desc;**

*desc = descending order

asc = ascending order*